# Android Media Duration returns wrong value

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer, android-service-binding, android-mediasession

I have set up my app using these:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/com/example/android/uamp/ui/FullScreenPlayerActivity.java

https://gist.github.com/ianhanniballake/15dce0b233b4f4b23ef8

The duration is displayed as 10, which I believe is because dividing 10000 in `putLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DURATION, 10000);`  by 1000 in `mEnd.setText(DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(duration/1000));` to get seconds format. But why 10000?

How do I get the original duration of the track being played?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was instead of 10000, I should have returned the media duration from the service itself.
like player.getDuration()
10000 was (i guess) just an example by ianhanniballake

Answer (score 0):

Time in long is normally in milliseconds, so you should divide by 1,000 (not 10,000) to get the amount of seconds.